# launch application from browser and start screen

Tags: android, url, browser, android-manifest

I am trying to be able to launch my app from a custom URL link like myurlscheme://myurl/123. Here is the start activity in the manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name="mainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:exported="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <data  android:scheme="myurlscheme" />

        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

The problem is that after adding the custom scheme, the app now longer shows up on the Android launch screen, when loading the apk, there is a message saying:

[2014-01-03 10:54:09 - myapp] No Launcher activity found!
[2014-01-03 10:54:09 - myapp] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!

Is there a way to manipulate the manifest file to be able to start the app with the same activity from both the start screen and the custom URL?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to combine all of your desired intent-filters into one intent filter. This is not how Android works; you must specify each desired intent filter in its own  element. For example:

```
<activity
    android:name="mainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:exported="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <data  android:scheme="myurlscheme" />

        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```